# Determine whether given series is convergent or not?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

> Consider the series 
>   $\sum_{1}^{\infty} \frac {1}{n(1+ 1/2 +...+1/n)}$

Let a<sub>n</sub> =  $\frac {1}{n(1+ 1/2 +...+1/n)}$ ~ $\frac{1}{n\log(n)}$

**Using Cauchy condensation test**,
$\sum_{1}^{\infty} \frac {1}{n(1+ 1/2 +...+1/n)}$  diverges.

Is my approach right?

Comment: it would help if you show how and what you proved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the approach is correct. First use the comparison test to show that the series has the same character as $\sum1/(n\log n)$ and then apply Cauchy's condensation test. Another way would be to use the integral test:
$$
\int_2^\infty\frac{dx}{x\log x}=\infty.
$$